# Can $A_n$ be generated by two elements $x,y$ with $x\ne 1$ arbitrarily chosen?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

We have this theorem

> **Theorem.** Let $x$ be any nontrivial element of the symmetric group $S_n$. If $n\ne 4$, then there exists an element $y\in S_n$ such that $S_n = \langle x,y\rangle$.

**My question:** is the similar statement of $A_n$ valid? That is, if we pick an arbitrary nontrivial element $x$ of $A_n$, can we always find a corresponding $y\in A_n$ such that $\langle x,y\rangle = A_n$?

I checked $A_4$, the statement is also valid for $n=4$. I think it is true but don't know how to prove it. It seems not to be a corollary of the above theorem.

One proof of the above theorem uses Jordan's theorem:

> If $G$ is a primitive subgroup of $S_n$ which contains a $p$-cycle with $p\le n-3$ be a prime, then $G = A_n$ or $G = S_n$.

Is this useful for the proof of $A_n$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not an answer, but a quick check on GAP says that it's true for $n \leq 8$ as well.

Comment: This is actually true in a stronger form for all finite simple groups, see [this nice survey](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.10434.pdf).

Comment: Really helps a lot! Thank you.@AndreasCaranti